# Advice for playing smoothly on mini synth keys

Tags: technique, synthesizer

I am struggling to play scales/runs at a smooth volume on my new mini synth, a Yamaha Reface CP. That I get accidentally loud notes mixed in, that really get into the harsh loud part of the sample and stick out. I think it has to do with the short light keys and differences in the lengths of my fingers. Consciously playing on the ends of the black notes for the mini keys seems to help. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

I have a classical piano background, and am trying to learn playing blues/jazz/rock stuff. I don't expect to play classical piano well on this thing, but I still want to be able to play smooth runs.

Comment: Is it not possible to turn off the touch sensitivity of the keys? On certain sounds it should be defeated anyway. As a concert pianist, you will have problems, both with the touch sensitivity and size of keys - just as you would if you'd played a mini synth then gone on to piano. Practising a lot may be your only answer.

Comment: If it has the option of selecting different keyboard velocity curves that could help quite a bit.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - that's what I meant by touch sensitivity. My 1st keyboard ever never had any sensitivity, and lost me the job in a band, as it sounded naff. Velocity curves may have helped, but that was best part of 50 yrs ago - sensitivity was rather expensive!

Comment: @Tim I do recall when touch sensitivity was an upgrade in some keyboards. I only commented since you suggested turning it off completely. I glanced at the manual online but didn’t see an adjustment for that but maybe I missed it. Funny thing, this keyboard costs almost $500 and it might not have touch/velocity adjustment but a mini 2 octave controller that cost me less than $100 does.

Comment: Would it be an option to use a digital piano as keyboard and the ReFace as a MIDI module?

Answer (score 0):

Besides some tactile training: perhaps you need to switch or deactivate some effects on this E-piano. Some effects can feel like a delay or a mispressed key.

You can also check with a second MIDI-instrument, like a DAW:

- establish a MIDI connection via USB with your computer
- use the CP just as a keyboard
- use a DAW as input AND assign various instruments (synthesizers) to this MIDI-track.

Instead of a DAW you can also use other virtual instruments. E.g. try the demo version from [pianoteq](https://www.modartt.com/), to better evaluate your CPs keybed. E.g. it will show you relevant MIDI data sent by your CP. So you can evaluate, how much fluctiation you have in your pressing of keys. Or look for other free MIDI-monitors to evaluate your key pressing.

Comment: I'd have thought OP's ears would be just as good, if not better, at evaluating key pressing - hence the question.

Comment: Yes ans no. In this instrument there can be a lot of confounding interactions. So the more ways you have to evaluate, the better. That‘s where MIDI can help, e.g. by switching off, what can‘t be influenced enough on the CP.